# Convert UILabel substring to UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a comments section in my app, where users can tag their friends. When loading the comments into the table view, I need to parse through each comment to see if it contains the `@` signal for a tagged friend, then get that substring and convert it to a `UIButton` that segues to the user's profile.

I already have `textLabel?.text` as `String?`, but I'm unsure of how to convert a substring of `String?` to a `UIButton`. Do I have to use an attributed string?

Answer (score 2):

If you need custom detection and if you want to be able to call any custom method after a user clicks on a particular word, you should first make your UITextView selectable and then check out `NSAttributedStrings` with an `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute that will point to a custom URL scheme. [Go through this Ray Wenderlich article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#textViewLinks)